# Using double integrals to find area between two graphs

Tags: calculus

> Find the area bounded by $y^2=x $ and $y=x$ in $xy$ plane.

I tried this:

$$\int^1_0\int^{x^\frac{1}{2}}_x dydx = \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this the correct answer?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: $\frac12$ clearly cannot be the correct answer when the entire right triangle spanned by the points $(0,0), (1,1), (0,1)$ has area $\frac12$, and you're only interested in a part of it. However, the integral you set up seems like it should give the correct answer, so perhaps you could tell us how you made that into $\frac12$, and we can tell you where it went wrong.

Comment: Do you really need a double integral ? Why not 
$$
\int_0^1\sqrt{x}\ dx - \int_0^1 x \ dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

You've set up the integral correctly, but something goes wrong in the evaluation.

Note that you can also integrate in the other order (avoiding the square root):
$$\int_0^1 \int_{y^2}^y \,\mbox{d}x \,\mbox{d}y = \int_0^1 y^2-y  \;\mbox{d}y = \ldots$$
Perhaps you can verify your calculations and compare it with what you get from the integral above, both should give you $\frac{1}{6}$ as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The double integral is correct but something went wrong in its evaluation.
$$\int^1_0\int^{\sqrt{x}}_x dydx=\int^1_0(\sqrt{x}-x)dx$$
Now recall that  $\int x^a dx=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}+c$ for $a\not=-1$.
Are you able to find the correct answer now?